# Get Ajax Loaded Html in WebView Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, ajax, android-webview

I'm trying to get the content of web page in android.. I've already tried using JSoup but it doesn't support using ajax..

So I'm trying to load url inside an invisible web view and get the html in `onPageFinished` method..

I can get the html but the ajax loaded html doesn't appear. Here's the code:

```
 final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.testWebView);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "HtmlViewer");
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d(TAG, "finished loading : ");
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                    "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
        }
    });
 webView.loadUrl(url);



class MyJavaScriptInterface {

    private Context ctx;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showHTML(String html) {
        Log.d(TAG, "HTML: " + html);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).setTitle("HTML").setMessage(html)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).setCancelable(false).create().show();
    }

}
```

So my questions are:

**-Why isn't the ajax html loaded with the page html ?**

**-Is there another way of loading page html with ajax using a library or something like that?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `webView.loadData()` method to load HTML file so, Replace the Ajax loading by this way.

```
webView.loadData("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                    "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');", "text/html; charset=utf-8",null);
```

I hope it will solve your problem .

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the WebView but I replaced webView.loadUrl with webView.loadData but the showHTML method is never called. onPageFinished is called constantly